# Why can't I place anything in a certain place?

Tags: dont-starve

I have a spot in my world where I can't place anything.
I've checked for fireflies and ice, and it didn't go away on season change.
I've also tried disabling all my mods.
If it's a shadow creature it's bugged, because I'm on max sanity and it's not moving.
Does anybody know what this might be?
I'm playing SW enabled ROG.

It's just above the "Build Campfire" in this image.

[image: It's just above the "Build Campfire"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so I did some more research, it looks like this is a tumbleweed spawnpoint. Darn, I really wanted to finish my bee farm.

Comment: Bright side: You could fence in the spawner and collect tumbleweeds without having to chase them down.